# Tensorflow works w/ GPU, but warns when invoked within R 'for' loop: 'triggered tf.function retracing'

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm using R/Keras/TensorFlow to implement a CNN for regression in the context of neuroscience analysis, and this entails applying the same TF model (exact same model structure and input dimensions) on hundreds of different X/Y combinations. The network runs and outputs expected values but complains about tensorflow being called repeatedly.

The schematic approach I took was

```
for (i in nrow(xy_combinations) {
 k_clear_session()
 model = keras_model_sequential() %>%  [model comes here]
 model %>% compile [details here]
 model %>% fit(as.array(x_train), as.matrix(y_train), epochs=50, batch_size=32, shuffle = FALSE, verbose=0)
 y_pred  =  model %>% predict(x_test))
 do_stuff(y_pred)
}
```

Everything works well (meaning I get similar and sane results for VMs configd for GPU or CPU), but after a few iterations on a GPU install, I receive a tensorflow warning of the sort:

> 5 out of the last 13 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at 0x7f0f19a59840> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive

I use k_clear_session and model (re)compiling to make sure the model doesn't maintain weights across 'fit' calls, because each invocation of the model applies to different X/Y pairs, with potentially very different relations.  Is there a saner way to implement this loop, within R, in a way that uses tensorflow optimally? I'd prefer not to have to code TF at the graph level and stay in R.

Thanks.